# parent child class animals zoo

Tags: python, oop, class, inheritance

This is a class design question in python.

I am trying to design three classes, one for animal, one for zoo, one for chicken farm.

```
class Animal:
    pass

class Zoo:

    def __init__(self, listOfAnimals)

    .....

class chickenFarm(Zoo):
   ....
```

Note ChickenFarm is a child of Zoo and uses many of the zoo methods. Additionally, the chicken farm has its unique methods related only to chicken.

My question is, how the zoo class (or object) mutates into a chickenFarm object once all the animals in the zoo are found to be chicken?  (Obviously the zoo class has methods that can add or remove animals)

in other words:

```
z=Zoo()

z.addAnimals()

z.removeanimals()

if z.testAllCkichen():
```

z now mutates into a chickenFarm objects

```
z.layEggs()
```

or maybe:

```
c=checkenFarm(z) # (when z now contains all chicken)

c.layEggs(0)
```

Comment: Just from a design perspective, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have `testAllChicken` as a method on Zoo.  It makes more sense to have that test be a static member of ChickenFarm.  If you wanted to be (maybe too) terse about it, you could even make it a class method that returned a ChickenFarm object if the test was true, and the original Zoo object if the test was false.  Then you would just have `z = ChickenFarm.testAllChicken(z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start to how you could implement `chickenFarm.__init__` so that when it gets a `Zoo` instance as its first argument it will create a `chickenFarm` that has its attributes copied from the `Zoo` instance:

```
class chickenFarm(Zoo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], Zoo):
            zoo = args[0]
            # copy all Zoo data from zoo to self
            # for example self.animals = zoo.animals.copy()
        else:
            Zoo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
z = Zoo()
# do some stuff
if z.testAllChicken():
    c = chickenFarm(z)
    c.layEggs()
```